# Why is my DropDownList empty on Postback?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've looked at answers to some similar question but I still can't seem to figure this out. I think I'm misunderstanding something about how ASP.NET works.

In the standard ASP.Net 4.0 'Create a new Account' form, I've added a DropDownList containing Roles to be selected for the new account. in the aspx page, the control looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RoleList" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I am then populating the List in the Page_Load Event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Set the Role List Selections
        DropDownList roleList = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RoleList");

        //set the role list
        String[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        foreach (String role in roles)
        {
            roleList.Items.Add(new ListItem(role, role));
        }
    }
```

I can see/select a role from the generated html. The problem arises when the 'Submit' button for creating a User is clicked:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

        string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
        {
            continueUrl = "~/";
        }

        //set user role
        DropDownList roleList = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RoleList");
        Roles.AddUserToRole(RegisterUser.UserName, roleList.SelectedValue);

        Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
    }
```

Here, The roleList object contains zero items, and has no selected values. Somehow, I am losing the populating items between selection of the item, and the submit. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your dropdownlist loading into the OnInit function instead - then it should be loaded properly when RegisterUser_CreatedUser is called:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    //Set the Role List Selections
    DropDownList roleList = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RoleList");

    //set the role list
    String[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    foreach (String role in roles)
    {
        roleList.Items.Add(new ListItem(role, role));
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks, now I just need to understand why.

Comment: @SP - OnInit takes place before Asp.Net loads values from the form into its objects. Page_Load takes place during the Load event, which occurs after the form is interrogated. Check out this page to learn about the page events in Asp.Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I read the page, but I still don't understand why my original code doesn't work correctly. Why would the Items in the DropDown disappear?

Comment: @SP - They disappear because they aren't loaded. Your code is telling Page_Load to return (meaning it leaves the function) before it has the chance to run that code. You need to remember that the web is basically stateless, so if you want something to show up on the page, you need to do it each time that page is requested.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Thanks @Charles Boyung. You saved me a great deal of time!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that change of radio button selection would auto postback the page and the dropdown list items would disappear after the page is back.

Solution

Check IIS -> Your WebSite -> Pages & Controls -> Enable Viewstate & Enable Sessionstate should be set to true.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code below bypasses the proper databinding on the page load.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
    return; 
}
```

You need to bind this control each time so that the values are present when click events are called. You may also get event errors for operating on selected items that are no longer present.

Comment: But if I do that, the selected index will always be 0 because it is repopulating after submit is clicked, but before RegisterUser_CreatedUser is called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try embracing your binding with the following condition?

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
{  
    //Binding goes here
}
```

Comment: @SP - that's true, but ncakmak's formatting is the more standard way of doing this sort of thing, so you may want to do things in this format anyways so others more easily understand your code.